# how do i pass data from one class to another and update an element's contents

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

I have two qooxdoo classes:

**main.container**:

```
qx.Class.define("main.container",
{
    type: "singleton",
    extend: webfrontend.gui.CustomWindow,

    construct: function() {
        this.base(arguments);
        this.setLayout( new qx.ui.layout.VBox());
        var info = new qx.ui.container.Composite( new qx.ui.layout.VBox());
        this.add(info);
        this.info = info;
    },
    destruct: function(){},
    members: {
        info: null,
        __setInfo: function(array) {
            this.info.removeAll();
            for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                var label = new qx.ui.basic.Label(array[i]);
                this.info.add(label);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**main.widget**:

```
qx.Class.define("main.widget",
{
    type: "singleton",
    extend: qx.ui.core.Widget,

    construct: function() { ... },
    members: {
        __sendData: function(data) {
            var cont = main.container.getInstance();
            var setInfo = cont.__setInfo;
            setInfo(data);
        },
        __onHover: function() {
            var data = ....
            this.__sendData(data);
        }
    }
});
```

What i'm trying to do is get data from the `main.widget` class and pass it to `main.container` class and add labels to the info container.

However, when i run this code i get this error `TypeError: Cannot call method 'removeAll' of undefined`, but when i run this in console: `main.container.getInstance().__setInfo([...])` it works!.

What i'm i doing wrong and how can i fix it?

[qooxdoo playground](http://tinyurl.com/pvy2u2l)

Answer (score 1):

Prefixing a method with two underscores like you did with __setInfo marks the method as private. This means only the class itself has access to this method. qooxdoo enforces this by renaming those kinds of methods during the build process. If you want to access this method from another class, you should implement it as a public method, which means not underscores at the beginning of the method name. Check out the manual page about Classes for more details: http://manual.qooxdoo.org/current/pages/core/classes.html?highlight=private%20protected#access

Comment: +1 for the private methods explanation i didn't know that before :),  however i still can't seem to get it to work! http://tinyurl.com/qyzvtof